# TextToColumns without result being evaluated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a csv with a "|"-delimeter, so I open the workbook:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xl_newest_export)
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
```

and use texttocolumns:

```
   ws.Range("A1:A" & CStr(lastRow)).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1:A" & CStr(lastRow)), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, DecimalSeparator:=".", Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="|"
```

However this fails as the text gets evaluated by Excel - a few doubles are getting converted to date. e.g.
"1" -> "01.01.1900"

How can I achieve the above with no Evaluation?

**Edit**:
As suggested in the comments - Fieldinfo is the solution. However I tried to build a Array-string... e.g. "Array(Array(3,1)...)" but this fails too..

Comment: In the normal import text wizzard you can set the column type. I don't know what the settings for that are in VBA, but perhaps recording a macro setting all columns to text might do the trick. Then nothing gets evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have filled column **A** with data, use this instead:

```
Sub PiedPipper()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, pipe As String

    Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    pipe = "|"
    For Each r In rng
        ary = Split(r.Value, pipe)
        r.Resize(1, UBound(ary) + 1) = ary
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Use this to get the `.csv` data into column **A**:

```
Sub GetCVSData()
   Dim FilesToOpen
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
   Dim ary, bry, DQ As String
   DQ = Chr(34)

   FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Text Files to Open")

   Close #1
   Open FilesToOpen For Input As #1

   j = 1
   Do While Not EOF(1)
      Line Input #1, TextLine
      With Cells(j, 1)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = TextLine
    End With
      j = j + 1
   Loop

   Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't work - I'm not sure why. to clarify: the string is very Long(about 540 columns). and it's possible to have missing values so... e.g. "a|b|||||abcdef|"

Comment: Thx - your formula works. My Problem is: I open the csv with Workbook.Open() - so Excel already tries to use a delimiter in the Background...which is not what I want of course

Comment: You clearly answered the question... my Problem is not solved though :/

Comment: @dv3  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: oh my, that's awesome... thanks for the big save Gary! have a good one